# Undefined reference to function from linked library

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to use the cblas library for matrix multiplication, but get "undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'" when I try to compile, even though the library should be linked properly.

Code in `test.c` looks like this:

```
...
#include <cblas.h>

void reference_dgemm (int N, double ALPHA, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
  int ORDER = 101; // row major
  char TRANSA = 111; // no transpose
  char TRANSB = 111;
  int M = N;
  int K = N;
  double BETA = 1.;
  int LDA = N;
  int LDB = N;
  int LDC = N;
  cblas_dgemm(ORDER, TRANSA, TRANSB, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, LDA, B, LDB, BETA, C, LDC);
}
```

is compiled like this:

```
gcc -lblas test.c
```

giving this error:

```
/tmp/cc9fVU41.o: In function `reference_dgemm':
test.c:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried using `#include <gsl/gsl_cblas.h>` with `-lgslcblas` instead, as in [this example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/GSL-CBLAS-Examples.html), same problem. Format and name of the referenced function I got from /usr/include/cblas.h

Comment: Did you install development packet of BLAS? I mean: `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev`

Comment: Libraries goes at the end of the command line. Do `gcc test.c -lblas`

Comment: @nos AFAIK not mandatory.

Comment: @LPs Yes it is, if you're using a modern toolchain.

Comment: And now it works. How did I not know this. Do you know _why_ they need to be at the end? man gcc doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: @nos a `gcc 4.9.2` does not care about the order. Eg. simple main with pow can be compiled with `gcc -o test test.c -lm` or `gcc -lm -o test text.c`

Comment: @LPs It's the version of the linker that matters in this regard, the `--no-copy-dt-needed-entries` and `--as-needed` was made default at some point  (at least on most distros)Make sure your tests doesn't constant fold your call to pow() though, in which case -lm isn't needed at all.

Comment: @user3047819 See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Comment: @nos My simple test does not use `pow` as `pow(2,3)` that does not require to link math lib. BTW it work both ways. Thx for your explanation. I learned something new today ;)

Comment: why you didn't know - this feature is new,   the man page is provided as a courtesy, the official GCC documentation is in texinfo, not man,